# How to describe Security Groups for a VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli, aws-security-group

Is there a way to describe a Security Group in a specific VPC?

Here is what I am trying to run :

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-name "<group-name>" --filter Name=vpc-id,Values=<my-vpc-id>
```

But it is returning this error :

```
A client error (VPCIdNotSpecified) occurred when calling the DescribeSecurityGroups operation: No default VPC for this user
```

I appreciate your help,

Thanks

Comment: After going over documentation once again, seems like we need to describe by "group-id" if we are querying for a non-default VPC. Reference : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-security-groups.html

Comment: Are you asking how to describe a *specific* security group, or all security groups in the given VPC? If it is a specific security group, do you wish to provide the name or the ID of the group?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To describe all security groups in a given VPC:

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters "Name=vpc-id,Values=vpc-abcd1234"
```

To describe a specific security group by its ID:

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-id sg-1234abcd
```

To describe a specific security group by its name (for non-default VPCs):

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters Name=group-name,Values=MY-SG
```

To describe a specific security group by its name and VPC (since there can be multiple groups with the same name in different VPCS):

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters Name=group-name,Values=MY-SG Name=vpc-id,Values=vpc-abcd1234
```

See [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) documentation: [describe-security-groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-security-groups.html)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for : `aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters Name=group-name,Values=MY-SG `

Comment: @ArunAvanathan, without adding the vpc (Name=vpc-id,Values=vpc-abcd1234) you risk returning similarly named groups once multiple VPCs are created in your account.  One example is the creation of a Windows VPC.  Let's say both VPCs create a group "infrastructure".  Your code will return both sg-ids unless it filters by vpc-id.

Comment: Thanks @Jason2616321 Thats right. And hence, we wanted a way to find with VPCid in the filter.